# Is this htaccess code right?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|zip|scripts|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

[This is the site](http://oket.andizm.net)

Notice, every link you click, the change is done in the address bar, but not on the page.

Whats the problem with this HTACCESS code?

Thnx in advance :-)

Comment: What do you mean the change is done in the address bar but not on the page ? what browser are you testing on ?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess code is right for what it meant to do. 
Appending index.php internally so you have a cleaner url in your browser address bar. Be clear on your question.
What you meant by "every link you click, the change is done in the address bar, but not on the page" ?